# Selecting Cases in Switch case statement in R

Tags: r, switch-statement

I am sorry if it seems like a foolish question but I wanna ask that does the case in the switch case statement always have to be a string for case selection in R?
The following code throws an error:

```
day = 2
weekday <- switch(day,
                  1 = "Sunday",
                  2 = "Monday",
                  3 = "Tuesday",
                  4 = "Wednesday",
                  5 = "Thursday", 
                  6 = "Friday",
                  7 = "Saturday",
                  "Invalid Input!!")
print(weekday)
```

But this code works perfectly:

```
day = 2
weekday <- switch(day,
                  '1' = "Sunday",
                  '2' = "Monday",
                  '3' = "Tuesday",
                  '4' = "Wednesday",
                  '5' = "Thursday", 
                  '6' = "Friday",
                  '7' = "Saturday",
                  "Invalid Input!!")
print(weekday)
```

How come day, which is a number is matched with a character in the switch case?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `nif` (nested if) and `vswitch` functions in package `kit`, I think this is what you are looking for. To access the documentation type `?kit::nif` after installing the package.

Answer (score 0):

If the expression being tested in the `switch()` is a number, then cases are matched by position, so you can leave out the argument names and do:

```r
day = 2
weekday <- switch(day,
                  "Sunday",
                  "Monday",
                  "Tuesday",
                  "Wednesday",
                  "Thursday", 
                  "Friday",
                  "Saturday",
                  "Invalid Input!!")
print(weekday)
# Output:
# [1] "Monday"
```

Comment: Okay, I understand this code. But what if the number is not an index, what if it's an id number I want to match?

Comment: You should convert the ID to string, so that matching happens by name. When testing this answer, I found that you can use numbers to name cases by quoting them, e.g. `\`1\` = "Monday"`, but then if the expression is a number, `switch()` still matches by position and ignores the name you gave the case! So you either have to use a number and match by position, or use a string and match by name, mixing the two gives confusing/wrong results.

Comment: Than you. It was helpful.